# SoundRecognition won't work, can't find a pyaudio moudule

Tags: python, bots, pyaudio, sound-recognition

I am trying to build a desktop assistant with sound_recognition, 
but it keeps saying

```
Cannot find PyAudio, Check installation
```

but when I try to do `pip install pyaudio` it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in 
c:\users\USERNAME\pycharmprojects\jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages (0.2.11).
```

I have tried `pipwin` and using the wheel file from online, where I got the message

`This is not a supported wheel on this platform`

or whatever that says. 
Please help me!

Comment: Have you checked if you use pip2 or pip3? Could be that you installed it for python 2.X and are using python 3.X

Comment: can you import pyaudio in python shell?

Comment: I checked and it said I am using pip for python 3.8, which is the version of python I am using.